# Finding roots of a polynomial using Python

Tags: python, math, polynomials

How to use python to find all the roots of a polynomial function? My code below works if all the coefficients `a, b, c, d, e` in the `my_func` function are removed, that is, if they are equal to 1. How could I edit the code so that `a, b, c, d, e` (the arguments in the polynomial_root function) are defined in the said function?

Code:

```
import numpy as np


def polynomial_root(a,b,c,d,e):
        p = np.poly1d([a,b,c,d,e])
        roots = p.roots
        return roots

def my_func(x):
  return a*x**4 + b*x**3 - c*x**2 + d*x - e

def print_format(x, f):
    for i in range(0,4):
        print("x={}\t\t f(x)={}\t\t".format(x[i],f(x[i])))
  

# Working with polynomials 8x**4 + 3x**3 - 2x**2 + 8x - 2

c = polynomial_root(8.,3.,-2.,8.,-2)

print("The solutions of f(x) = 8x**4 + 3x**3 - 2x**2 + 8x - 2 are:")
print_format(c, my_func)
```

Comment: The very first thing in the [numpy documentation page about polynomials](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.polynomials.html) is that `numpy.poly1d` is only included for backwards compatibility with prior versions of numpy, and `numpy.polynomial` is recommended instead.

Comment: Also note `my_func` should return `a*x**4 + b*x**3 + c*x**2 + d*x + e`, not `a*x**4 + b*x**3 - c*x**2 + d*x - e`, since the minus signs are already in the coefficients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your implementation of `my_func`, there are two problems:

- you use `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` and `e` as if they were global variables, but anywhere else you pass those coefficients as parameters
- you change the sign of `c` and `e`, therefore evaluating a different polynomial

a fixed version of your code could look like this:

```
import numpy as np


def polynomial_root(coefficients):
        p = np.poly1d(coefficients)
        return p.roots


def evaluate_polynomial(coefficients, x):
  result = 0
  for c, power in enumerate(reversed(coefficients)):
    result += c * x**power
  return result


def print_format(x_values, coefficients, f):
    for x in x_values:
        print("x={}\t\t f(x)={}\t\t".format(x, f(coefficients, x)))
  

# Working with polynomials 8x**4 + 3x**3 - 2x**2 + 8x - 2

coefficients = [8.,3.,-2.,8.,-2]
roots = polynomial_root(coefficients)

print("The solutions of f(x) = {}x**4 + {}x**3 + {}x**2 + {}x + {} = 0 are:".format(coefficients))
print_format(roots, coefficients, evaluate_polynomial)
```

Comment: Or `def evaluate_polynomial(coefficients, x): return np.polyval(coefficients, x)`

Comment: interesting, I didn't know about that function. I think in this case it is possible to pass `np.polyval` directly to `print_format`

Comment: There is also `np.polynomial.polynomial.polyval`, which is similar to `np.polyval`, except these two functions confusingly expect their arguments in reverse order, ***and*** the coefficients in reverse order: `np.polynomial.polynomial.polyval(x, coeffs) == np.polyval(coeffs[::-1], x)`